# No module named 'keras_tuner'

Tags: python, auto-keras

I'm executing this code on Kaلgle, and install autokeras library on it,

```
!pip install autokeras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
import datetime
%matplotlib inline


#Control the default size of figures in this Jupyter notebook
%pylab inline 
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (14, 9) # Change the size of plots

#cib = pd.read_csv("../input/balmhils1/balmhils1015.csv") 
# load data from csv 
cib_f = pd.read_csv("../input/jkse1234/JKSE.csv") # load data from csv
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,8))
plt.xlabel("Number of trading day")
plt.ylabel("Close price")
```

but I got this error.
No module named 'keras_tuner'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade the `keras_tuner`

```
!pip install keras-tuner --upgrade
```

Comment: !pip install keras-tuner --upgrade if doing in google collab

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using PyCharm. When I installed the keras-tuner package in the Anaconda 3 prompt, I got the message that everything is already installed. The problem was, that the keras-tuner was installed in my base environment and not in the environment (virtual) which I use in PyCharm. You simply need to do the following.

1. check out your environments in the anaconda prompt using: `conda env list`
   you will probably see the * on the base environment
2. now change to your working environment for example `conda activate tf_cpu` -> tf_cpu needs to be changed by your envs name (see on your list)
3. install your package such as `pip install keras_tuner`

Answer (score 0):

otherwise try to execute the statement below
from kerastuner import RandomSearch
from kerastuner.engine.hyperparameters import HyperParameters